# Why am I not able to type anything in the terminal window after running npm start in order to fire up the development server?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

I am using create-react-app tool to create a React project. But after running npm start command in my terminal window in order to fire up the development server, I am not able to type anything in the terminal. Why so and how can I rectify it?

[image]

Comment: You can open another terminal for other purposes at the same time

Answer (score 1):

That terminal command is still running (specifically it is running your server) so it can't take anymore commands. If you want to run other commands while it is running, you will have to open another terminal tab/window. The `+` button in the top right of the terminal window should do it for you

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl c twice it will show you ^c
Then you can write your command under the ^c